# Crazy comic that I read in 80's (Probably Marvel)

Tags: story-identification, marvel

This was an intro to a longer story in a comic book that was probably Marvel that I read in the 80s. I never read the subsequent parts to the story so I do not have a lot of detail.

This first episode introduced a "regular looking" middle-age guy who had always started his work day in the same way, driving to work. In this intro however it was displayed that he had the ability to modify the reality (in a certain way) just by wishing for the modification.

For example (if I remember this exactly correct) in this introductory story he had left home at a bad time (rush hour traffic or something) and wished that he would have left earlier. Because he wished for that, it came true and he was transferred back in time (or something like that - at least the other cars disappeared from the road).

This first episode ended with some character - that looked like an angry living version of the sun (meaning, literally, he looked like a round fiery star with a face on it) - that was looking for someone else. It's possible that he was looking for this middle-age guy, but I do not remember.

What Marvel(?) story was this and who were the middle-age guy and the star characters?

Comment: How sure are you that it was a Marvel comic?

Comment: @RogueJedi, ok good question. I think I predominantly only read Marvel comics back in those days but I could be wrong. If I were to set some kind of number for this certainty it would be 80%.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're thinking of [L. R. "Skip" Collins](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Skip_Collins). He appeared in [Fantastic Four vol. 1 #234 (1981)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_234) during the John Byrne run.

As a young man, Skip Collins spent time in the Army and was exposed to radiation during a nuclear weapon test. He developed the ability to alter reality, but being a generally unimaginative person, he never realized it. He goes on to live a mundane, middle class life. The story depicts his power triggering subconsciously when he faces life's little problems and wishes things were different than they are.

Much of issue 234 follows Collins as he travels to New York City on a business trip. While he's there, a series of earthquakes wracks the planet, causing large-scale destruction and no doubt millions of deaths.

Eventually the FF discover that the destruction is being caused by the approach of [Ego, the Living Planet](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ego_(Earth-616)). They fly off to save the day. Collins sees the destruction and the FF apparently abandoning the city, and in a moment of total despair wishes it had all never happened. This triggers his power to undo all of the destruction, still without him realizing it.

[The next issue](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_235) is set completely off-world and depicts the fight between the FF and Ego. There's no further appearance by Collins, and readers never see what happens when the FF return to earth and find everything is back to normal.

Comment: haha, that is indeed it. Thanks Kenster. I have to wait 23 hours to award the bounty:-P